# Combined form input values in component state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Need help for combining two inputs values at one state key.
When make change at **Arrival date** input can read the new value at `data.arrivalDate` and respectively when make change to **Arrival time** input can read it's value from `data.arrivalTime`.

What I want to do is, when click on the Submit button - before send the data - to combine results from both inputs in a single state field `arrivesAt` so to recieve string like `2020-01-01/09:05`, so I don't need the old state keys `data.fromDate` & `data.fromTime` in my `data` object at all.

**Here goes my code:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-tdd-xesmm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: why do you need new state and cant use  ` ${data.fromDate}/${data.fromTime} `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On submit action in `handleSubmit`, you can just set state with `arrivalAt` value using template literals like

```
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setData(prev => ({
      arriveAt: `${prev.fromDate}/${prev.fromTime}`,
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.toUTCString()` function to turn your Date objects into strings and use things like `.split()` and `.slice()` to cut them up.

You can then add them together to create the string that you want before submitting it to where you want it to go.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this way but every time when hit the submit button gettin' previous state, not the current one. What am I missing? My code was a liitle bit messy at the begining so fixed it.

```js
  const handleChange = event => {
    let target = event.target;
    let value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    let name = target.name;
    setData(previousData => ({
      ...previousData,
      [name]: value
    }));
    if (target.type == "date" || target.type == "time") {
      setData(previousData => ({
        ...previousData,
        arrivesAt: `${data.arrivalDate} & ${data.arrivalTime}`
      }));
    }
  };
```